# React Router Not Working: Receiving no errors but rendering nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React JS, and I'm having problems with React Router. Router is simply not working!  I've tried several different sytax, but no luck.  The code provided below does not give me an error, but nothing renders onto my index.php page.

My main entry js file is index.js and it looks like this:

**index.JS:**

```
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import  {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Match, Miss, hashHistory}  from 'react-router';
        import {TopNavigation, SideNavigation}  from "./components/MainNav";
        import AllShipments from "./components/shipments";
        import RouterNav from "./components/RouterNav";
        import IndividualShipment from "./components/individualShipment";
        import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";


        "use strict"
        require('../scss/custom.scss');



        class ContentContainer extends React.Component  {
            render () {
            return (

            <div>

                <TopNavigation/>
                <RouterNav/>

                <div className="section-wrap-b floatDown">
                    <div className="widget-header">
                        <h3>HEADER</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Router history={hashHistory} >
                    <Route path="/" component={AllShipments} />
                    <Route path="/individualshipment" component={IndividualShipment} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                </Router>

                <Match exactly pattern='/' component={AllShipments}/>
                <Match pattern='/individualshipment' component={IndividualShipment}/>
                <Match pattern='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
            </div>  
            )
        }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(

            <ContentContainer/>,
            document.getElementById('root-content-area')
        );
```

Sample component structure looks like this in the AllShipments.js, Individualshipmn.js, Dashboard.js

**Sample:**

```
        import React from "react";
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';




        const Dashboard = () => {
            return (
                <div>   
                            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                </div>
            );
        };
        export default Dashboard;
```

**package.json file:**

```
        {
          "name": "js-practice",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "webpack.config.js",
          "scripts": {
            "babel": "babel",
            "webpack": "webpack",
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
            "build": "webpack -d && cp src/app.js dist/bundle.js && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
            "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/app.js dist/bundle.js"
          },
          "author": "Adam Donatelli",
          "license": "ISC",
          "devDependencies": {
            "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
            "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
            "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
            "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
            "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
            "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
            "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
            "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
            "fast-sass-loader": "^1.2.5",
            "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
            "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
            "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
            "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
            "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
            "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
            "webpack": "^3.0.0"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "history": "^4.6.3",
            "jquery": "^3.2.1",
            "react": "^15.6.1",
            "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
            "react-router": "^4.1.1"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `exact` attribute to the home path?, like this: `<Route exact path="/" component={AllShipments} />` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool Basically now all your routes match the forward slash therefore when you try to go to a new route you react router sees that it matches the forward slash. Also be sure to use react router dom: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Thank you for the response.  You were certainly right about having to use react-router-dom.  I was also having an issue with importing my js files into other js files which was causing me issues in merging all my components together.   I figuered out that my import objects needed to be corrected.   In my "sample" component above I included the ' return () ' in my component.  When importing this "sample component into js files other than the main export js file (index.js), both files would not render.  I removed the 'return ()' and this has resolved my importing issues.